# C++ comp(a,a)==false

Tags: c++, sorting

I was using lambda function in sort() function. In my lambda function I return true if two are equal. Then I got segmentation error.

After reviewing [C++ Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare), it says

```
For all a, comp(a,a) == false
```

I don't understand why it must be false. Why can't I let `comp(a,a)==true`?

(Thanks in advance)

Comment: compare tells you if a is placed before b when ordered. a cannot be before a, ergo false.

Comment: @user4581301 why not a cannot be before a? If a is before a, it is still sorted.

Comment: Because a is a. Let's hear it for Ayn Rand.

Comment: Lolz aside, think of it like this if a<b return true if a>=b return false. This is the contract defined by compare. In terms of sorting, if you allowed a=b to return true, you'd have to move more elements.

Comment: if a<=b return true, a>b return false @user4581301

Comment: That would violate the contract of the compare relationship. Some algorithms may respond poorly, such as going into infinite loop swapping a and a-prime back and forth forever.

Comment: @user4581301 is this contract C++ specific or all programming language apply to this?

Comment: @ShadowGiraffe Algorithms do not depend on the language they are implemented in, this is a math thing.

Answer (score 4):

Think of `Comp` as some sort of *"is smaller than"* relationship, that is it defines some kind of ordering on a set of data.

Now you probably want to do some stuff with this relationship, like sorting data in increasing order, binary search in sorted data, etc.

There are many algorithms that do stuff like this very fast, but they usually have the requirement that the ordering they deal with is "reasonable", which was formalized with the term [*Strict weak ordering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). It is defined by the rules in the link you gave, and the first one basically means:

*"No element shall be smaller than itself."*

This is indeed reasonable to assume, and one of the things our algorithms require.